# VB .Net Web Forms with Ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, ninject, ninject.web

I have recently used C# with Ninject.Web in a Web forms project. I used package manager console to install it using

```
PM> Install-Package Ninject.Web
```

This worked great. Now i have a VB .Net project (again Web forms) and would like to do the same. After running the above i noticed NinjectWeb and NinjectWebCommon were in C#.

So i converted them classes and still couldnt get Ninject to work with VB .Net. I researched around and got mixed results (i.e. some say you can do this and others say you cant) i tried a few ways but i think i got confused with the amount of articles probably targeting previous versions or im just doing something wrong.

Is there a simple way to use Ninject with VB .Net? Is there a working package i can use? I checked http://www.ninject.org/ which didnt give me many clues.

I found this article http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/2049/nuget-packages-and-vb-net-application-start-code which seems to be targeting EntityFramework which i dont think will work with Web Forms.

Appreciate any help or anyone that can put me on the right track.

Comment: what specifically are you having problems with using ninject? setting up your IoC container? do you have code samples?

Comment: I'm using Ninject as dependency injection (that is adding the services to the class which allows me to call them from any page)